# Delete-Orphan in ManyToMany Relation - JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Well, I have a table called 'Orcamento' that have a lot of 'ItemOrcamento'. I have another table called 'Consulta' that can have a lot of 'ItemOrcamento' too.

The table 'Consulta' can have a lot of 'ItemOrcamento' and one 'ItemOrcamento' can be within many 'Consulta'.

After understand the scenario, i will explain my problem: In JPA i did the relation bellow:

```
 @ManyToMany(fetch = javax.persistence.FetchType.LAZY)   
    @JoinTable(name = "item_consulta", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "id_consulta") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "id_item_orcamento") })   
    private Set<ItemOrcamento> itens;
```

When i create a new "Consulta" with a lot of "ItemOrcamento", the rows are inserted normally in table "item_consulta". Imagine something like that:

```
 consulta.addItem(item1);
 consulta.addItem(item2);
```

But now i wanna replace the item1 to item3, so i do it:

```
 consulta.addItem(item3);
 consulta.addItem(item2);
```

In my mind, Hibernate (JPA) must remove the orphan "item1" and add "item3", but it just add "item3" and the "item1" continue in database.

How can i solve it ?

**EDIT 1**

My relation is UNI-DIRECTIONAL, in "ItemOrcamento" i don't wanna a Set, because i don't need, so in ItemOrcamento i don't have any @ManyToMany anotation referencing the joinTable "item_consulta"

Comment: adding items will not remove already present items. and what do you do on the inverse side of the relation (the items)? operating just on one side of the relation will not remove the whole relation.

Comment: The above code reads like this in fact: add item1. Add item2. Add item3. Add item2... oh, that one already exists, I don't have to add it again (Set does not allow duplicates). If you want to remove something, use one of the actual removal methods (such as remove()) of the Set interface.

Comment: i think that cascade delete-orphan can do it for me.

Comment: @Gimby, as i said i removed the "item1" from Set interface and tried save without this "item1", but Hibernate don't remove the "item1" from database.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to manually remove unwanted items from your collection, then add new items:

```
consulta.remove(item1);   
consulta.addItem(item3);
```